# Checking all values w/ PHP of an array in a SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to check an array of parameters in a SQL Query from my API URL ( using slim-skeleton ).
I've got a route /services/ which gives me an array of 'services' :

```
$app->get('/services/[{service}]',function($request, $response, $args){
$services[] = $args['service'];
```

I need to make a query with my $service[] var to check all providers offering these services.
Here are my tables :

```
Services-----
     provider | label
  ----------------------
     18uxQ2lp | mCut
     18uxQ2lp | wColor
     12dzjux6 | chCut

Provider-----
     provider* | Name
  ----------------------
     18uxQ2lp | Erika
     6sx25jdo | Jess
     12dzjux6 | Mike
```

*( Edit : the license column from the provider table is now called "provider" )

I need to get the "provider" row in my Services table which verifies all the values from my array $services and then make a new SQL query to get the Name ( and other informations ) from my Provider table using the license.
I tried with the IN($services) statement, but it calls a provider only for one service.. not all..

I've been working on it all night long... can someone help me w/ this ?

Comment: i am thinking about using `GROUP_CONCAT`. Like `SELECT provider, GROUP_CONCAT(label) FROM services GROUP BY provider`. Then you can compare the results with your array in PHP

Comment: @LelioFaieta I just get all providers from my Services table, and then compare w/ my array ? But how can I just get providers that verify all values from my array ?

Comment: Your tables are a bit weird. The 'provider' column in the table 'Services' seems to refer to the 'license' column in the table 'Provider'? So what does the content of the 'provider' and 'license' columns represent? A license? Then they should both be called 'license'. As to your question, I think you need a JOIN of these two tables.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you're right.. I nammed them without thinking.. "license" and "provider" refer to an uniqid() for the providers...

Comment: Your `$services` is an array of `label`, isn't it? I think you need something like `Services JOIN Provider on Services.provider = Provider.license WHERE label IN ($services)`

Comment: @blueqn Tried your way.. I got the join between the 2 tables but it shows me any row w/ one service called.. How can I just call rows that verify all services ?

Comment: assume `$services = ['mCut', 'chCut']`, what is expected result?

Comment: @blueqn Somethg like that ? Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [label] => mCut [reference] => [provider] => 18uxQ2lp [name] => Erika ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [label] => chCut [reference] => [provider] => 18uxQ2lp [name] => Erika ) )

Comment: I dont see any problem with `JOIN` here. what is your code and the actual result?

Comment: @blueqn Here is what I've got... Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [label] => mCut  [provider] => 18uxQ2lp [name] => Erika ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [label] => chCut [provider] => 12dzjux6 [name] => Mike ) ) using this code : SELECT * FROM services INNER JOIN provider ON services.provider = provider.provider WHERE label IN($services[0])

Comment: As I see, actual result is correct result and your expected result is incorrect because `Erika` is not the provider of `chCut`.

Comment: @blueqn Of course, made a mistake in the expected result.. but my idea is to get only the provider which verifies 'mCut' and 'chCut', both and not just one.. and if no one does it, it should gives an array NULL. – I want to get like : Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [label] => mCut [provider] => 18uxQ2lp [name] => Erika ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [label] => wColor [provider] => 18uxQ2lp [name] => Erika ) ) or Array() if no one does it.